# Excel VBA how do I make the Enter key behave like the Tab key

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like the enter key to function just like the tab key does when using the worksheet to enter values. I'm not sure if that's enough information for you to help me so just ask questions if it's not.

I was able to find a setting in Tools>Options>Edit Move selection after enter - right. I'd like that same functionality but only for the one specific worksheet.

Comment: in a user form or in a worksheet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection` property - best to set in a `Workbook_Open()`.

e.g.

```
Application.MoveAfterReturn = True  ' here we say thou shallst move
Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight  ' here we say move right
```

Hope that helps
Good luck
MikeD

**edit:**

if you have more than 1 book open in the same application, you better use Workbook and Sheet Activate and Deactivate triggers as well to limit the effect to the narrowest possible

**edit 2:**

you can maybe save the original status in a trigger in the `ThisWorkbook` module

```
Dim OldDirection As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    OldDirection = Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = OldDirection
End Sub
```

and rely on `Sheet_Activate` and `Sheet_Deactivate` to actually set the property to `xlToRight` and reset it to `OldDirection` (so whatever the user chose as standard behaviour). Test with multiple open workbooks, jump back and forth; these triggers not always do the obvious at obvious times ....

Comment: would i use if then statements with sheet activate and deactivate triggers? and if i close the application would it automatically set it back to the default?

Comment: I don't see a reason to implement further conditions in workbook or sheet activate/deactivate triggers. And **yes** the current status of `MoveAfterReturnDirection` is retained after application closure. It's the same as if you change the setting via Tools/Options/Edit

Comment: is there a way to change it back to its default on close? maybe set a variable and in Workbook_Close() an Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = variable? this excel document will be used on multiple computers and i don't want to change their personal settings. Any ideas? Thanks for your ongoing help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: the function acts on the user's Excel application, it doesn't store any status in the worksheet. Re personal settings see my Edit-2